# i3 Window Manager switch window

Tags: linux, i3-window-manager

So I do have i3 window manager on my Manjaro Linux. When I want to focus the windows on the left/right I just prest `mod+left/right arrow` and thats it. But now I launched 4 terminal windows (2 at the top, and 2 at the bottom). When I am for example in the `left upper corner` window, and I go to the window below it with `cmd+down arrow` it focuses the `left lower corner` window, thats correct. But when I want to then switch to the windows on the `right side`, so that would be the windows in the `right lower corner` I press `mod+right arrow` but it switches to `right upper corner` window, so then I have to press `mod+down arrow` to get to the window I wanted to. Can I somehow make it switch to the correct window?

Comment: not really.  the order in which you open the windows can affect which arrows "work properly always". but crossing a certain container boundary always activates the last-used-window-in-that-container instead of the position you want.  (try a 2x3 layout instead to see.)  i think [this issue](https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/1160) describes (poorly) the bug you're seeing.

Comment: @quixotic The linked bug actually describes an issue where `i3` may *not* focus the last used window in a different container, but the nearest window. This can only happen with multiple displays and certain container constellations and configuration settings.

Comment: @Adaephon sure, possibly.  it's a very poor description.  if that's not the same bug a new issue should be raised.

Comment: The way I understand the question, the issue seems to be that instead of moving focus "intuitively",`i3` always focuses the last active window when moving focus between containers. This would not be a bug but intentional.